# Un-Escaped HTML for Variables in Guide Template Language Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, gtl

We have HTML templates in ExactTarget that use variables passed in via the REST API.  The variable contains text with HTML entities.

I read the following documentation for the Guide Template Language.

[Guide Template Language](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/guide_template_language/guide_template_language_syntax_guide/)

I set up a test template with the following.

```
<p><em>{{Custom_Text}}<em></p>
<p><em>{{Custom_Text [format=html]}}<em></p>
<p><em>{{Custom_Text [f=html]}}<em></p>
<p><em>{{& Custom_Text}}<em></p>
<p><em>{{{Custom_Text}}}<em></p>
```

In every case the email generated displays HTML entities as the literal entity text.

What we pass in:

```
&Rcy;&ocy;&scy;&scy;&icy;&yacy;
```

What is actually displayed:

```
&Rcy;&ocy;&scy;&scy;&icy;&yacy;
```

The actualt HTML generated:

```
&amp;Rcy;&amp;ocy;&amp;scy;&amp;scy;&amp;icy;&amp;
```

So it seems the template is replacing the `'&'` character in the HTML entity with the `'&amp;'` HTML entity.

I have not found a way to disable this.

Comment: Actually it seems that placing any HTML entities in a template will result in the entity getting HTML escaped.  It doesn't matter if they are a variable or not.

Comment: I opened a case in Salseforce against this issue and they replied saying that they could not help with debugging my code.  I replied that I believe it's a bug in their templates.  The case was then deleted, not closed, just deleted.  Very helpful.

Comment: What REST route are you using to pass this in?  Can you provide an example payload?

Comment: Unfortunately I recently changed jobs so I don't have the exact REST route or payload.  Basically it was just using the ExactTarget REST API for a triggered send so it was very much like their sample code.  See the following URL.    https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html       As I also found out it doesn't matter if the HTML entity is passed via the REST API, even if HTML entities are used in the body of the template, the HTML entity is still escaped.